# PointNormal to PointXYZ transfer problem

Tags: c++, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to transfer some PointNormal values to PointXYZ. I tried by following way, but it gave error. How can I do this?

```
int main(...) 
{ 
......... 
........ 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal> mls_points; 

// Init object (second point type is for the normals, even if unused) 
pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal> mls; 
...................................... 
..................................... 
mls.process (mls_points); 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr mls_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>); 


                  for (size_t i = 0; i < mls_points.points.size(); ++i) 
                  { 
                          mls_cloud->points[i].x=mls_points.points[i].x; //error 
                          mls_cloud->points[i].y=mls_points.points[i].y; //error 
                          mls_cloud->points[i].z=mls_points.points[i].z; //error 
                  } 
................................ 

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61642/pointnormal-to-pointxyz-transfer-problem./) by [Nihad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4554/nihad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wjwhynot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20151/wjwhynot/) on 2014-12-02**:
Thanks ,xoxo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to resize your target point cloud (`mls_cloud`).  The constructor creates the cloud object, but doesn't know how many points you want to store.  You can't just start assigning point data by index until you first allocate space to store them.

Try this:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr mls_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>); 
mls_cloud->resize(mls_points.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i < mls_points.points.size(); ++i) 
{ 
    mls_cloud->points[i].x=mls_points.points[i].x; //error 
    mls_cloud->points[i].y=mls_points.points[i].y; //error 
    mls_cloud->points[i].z=mls_points.points[i].z; //error 
}
```

Alternatively, you can dynamically build the cloud if you don't know ahead-of-time how many points it will contain:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr mls_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>); 

for (size_t i = 0; i < mls_points.points.size(); ++i) 
{
    const pcl::PointNormal &mls_pt = mls_points.points[i];
    pcl::PointXYZ pt(mls_pt.x, mls_pt.y, mls_pt.z);
    mls_cloud.push_back(pt);
}
```

Or, even better, don't re-create the wheel, and use the built-in PCL [copyPointCloud](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__common.html#gaff182bca8d0295d727baaa1fd368c6ad) function to convert cloud types:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr mls_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
copyPointCloud(cloud_xyz, cloud_xyzrgb);
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nihad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4554/nihad/) on 2013-04-27**:
Thnx. First one works fine.